# Which technology is internally used for az copy comand?

Tags: azure, data-transfer, command-line-tool, azcopy, azure-sdk-for-java

I wanted to understand the internal mechanism of Azure az copy command line utility that is used for data copy.

There are many blogs out there having the details about how to use AZ copy and different options it offers. But none of them actually explains how az copy actually works, as in, the internal mechanism/working for copying data used by az copy.

Comment: Please check the source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy

Comment: It's open-source, available at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy - and makes use of the go library for azure storage found at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/